# Element with display set to inline-block does not work in MVC for loop

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a for loop in my MVC Razor view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   <div class="myInlineBlockElement">some value</div>        
}
```

And the class `myInlineBlockElement` has a style `display: inline-block`.

The problem is that I cannot make the for output the div all in sequence. It always get pretty formatted in output. Because of this, there is some spaces between the divs (as it would be expected from a inline-block).

Is there a way to output the for loop elements in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Placing the elements with no spaces between them isn't the only way to get around the gap which appears between `inline-block` elements. Instead you can use CSS to give the parent of your `div` elements a `font-size` of 0, then re-add your desired `font-size` on the `div` elements themselves.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}

.myInlineBlockElement {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="myInlineBlockElement">some value</div>   
    <div class="myInlineBlockElement">some value</div>   
    <div class="myInlineBlockElement">some value</div>   
    <div class="myInlineBlockElement">some value</div>   
</div>
```

As you can see, there are no gaps between the `.myInlineBlockElement` elements in the above snippet.

Comment: font-size of 0 is a problem for Android: http://codepen.io/stowball/details/LsICH

Comment: @Marlos there are plenty of alternatives: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Actually, your link was my first reference. The comments doesn't look to work in Razor, the closing tag for <a> isn't working and - unfortunately - negative margin is a issue for old IE which is a requirement for me.